# Is survival regression really just a GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, survival

this is my first time asking a question so please be gentle.

I have never taken a course in survival analysis, but at work I am being tasked with fitting a survival model anyway.  So I dove into a textbook from our library and started reading about it.  I found that, after messing with hazard functions and the like, survival regression really just boils down to the following:

If $T$ is the response variable (time to failure), let $Y = \log T$.  Covariates $Z$.  If we fit the commonly used exponential or Weibull regression models, the model takes the form:

$$Y = \alpha + Z^T \beta + W$$

Where $W$ has an extreme value distribution (in the case of Weibull, scaled by a factor $\sigma$).  From grad school, I am pretty well trained in GLMs.  This looks a *lot* like a GLM, where the response is extreme value (Gumbel?) distributed.  I haven't gotten into the specifics of how the models are actually computed, but I assume it will be some sort of IRLS.

Am I correct here?  Or is there something inherently different about survival regression that makes it not a GLM?

Comment: It requires data on time to event with possible right censoring for cases where the event has not occurred at the time of analysis.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but does that in some way preclude it from being considered a GLM?  If so, why?

Comment: Maybe this one can give you some help on understanding the survival analysis: http://bit.ly/2ohX85g

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585057/survival-analysis-generalised-linear-regression-with-complementary-log-log-clo